# Websphere Liberty Profile Can't find bundle for base error

Tags: eclipse, classloader, websphere-liberty

I have an EAR installed in eclipse on WLP 8.5.5.3

This is the EAR entry with a classloader attached:

```
<enterpriseApplication id="App4EAR" location="App4EAR-4.1.5-SNAPSHOT.ear" name="App4EAR">
    <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api" delegation="parentFirst" commonLibraryRef="baseLibraries.app4">
    </classloader>
</enterpriseApplication>
```

The server is starting without issues. The first jsp page in the application tries to read a properties file which is located in the WAR component. This is where it fails.

```
SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException:1427' 
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name prop.appadmin, locale nl_BE
```

The object that reads the properties is located in the web application together with the properties file. The utility class for reading the resource bundle is in a separate jar and is part of a shared library (baseLibraries.app4).

This is an entry from the App4EAR.ear.xml deployment definition that points to folder where the properties file is located:

```
<dir sourceOnDisk="C:\svn\app4\App4Web\target\classes" targetInArchive="/WEB-INF/classes"/>
```

When using java.util.ResourceBundle() directly in the application it successfully locates the properties file. But not so when we use the utility class from the shared library.

Why is a shared library not able to access properties resources in the main web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packaging the utility jar, that accesses the resource file, in the web application solves the problem.

This solution kind of negates the purpose of shared libraries. Also note that on WAS 8.5 this was not a problem, so something did change in the way shared libraries are exposed/loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your shared library is loaded in parent classloader, and the classes and also properties in your application are not visible to that classloader thats why they cannot be found. Add property files to the classpath of the library instead of web app.

Comment: The properties files contain configuration settings (default theme, ...) for the web application, and therefore cannot be packaged with the utility library (logging, resource helpers, .. ).

Comment: Packaging the utility jar in the war instead of defining it as shared library works. This behavior makes shared libraries kind of obsolete.